# Finitely generated as a field?

Tags: field-theory

What does the following mean? For a field extension $E/F$ let $E$ be finitely generated as a field over $F.$ Does this mean that there exist $e_1, ..., e_n$ in $E$ such that every element in $E$ can be expressed in the form $f_1e_1 + ... + f_ne_n$ where $f_i \in F?$

Comment: No, all rational functions in the generators with non-zero denominator.

Answer (score 3):

[Here they suggest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_algebra) that "finitely generated **as a field**" means that $E$ is of the form $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ where $n$ is finite and the $x_i$ can be algebraic or transcendental.

The $x_i$ are algebraic ($E/F$ is a finite extension) iff $E$ is a finitely generated $F$-algebra (and a finite dimensional $F$-vector space). In that case $E = F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ (the ring generated by the $x_i$).

Otherwise, one of the $x_i$ is transcendental and $F(x)$ is not a finitely generated $F$-algebra (as an algebra, it is generated by $x$ and $\frac{1}{p(x)}$, $p \in F[x]$ irreducible)

Answer (score 0):

To take a simple example, if $x$ is an indeterminate, the field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is finitely generated (as a field) over $\mathbb{Q}$, but when regarded as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, the field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is not finite dimensional, since, in particular, the elements $1,x,x^2,x^3,...$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.